# Any proper way to achieve locks in a situation like this?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I have an array of objects that I want to operate on in threads, but I also want to be able to access at times. This feels like a hacky way to achieve my goal, but is there a better way to do something like this?:
＊the basic goal is to have 2 locks. One that allows all individual threads to work concurrently while blocking access from the array until they are all finished, and one that allows shuts down access from the thread to ensure that no objects are touched by other threads while a function runs.

```
atomic<int> inThreadCount;
atomic<int> arrayLock;
map<string, MyObj*> myMap;
mutex mu1;
class MyObj{
    mutex mu2;
    int myInt;
    public: 
    void update(bool shouldLowerCount){
        mu2.lock();
        myInt++;
        if (shouldLowerCount)
            inThreadCount--;
        mu2.unlock();
    }
}
//Some operation that requires all threads to finish first
//and doesn't allow threads to access the objects while running
void GetSnapshot(){ 
    mu1.lock();
    arrayLock++;
    while (inThreadCount > 0)
        Sleep(0);
    map<string, MyObj *>::iterator it = myMap.begin();
    auto t = time(nullptr);
    auto tm = *localtime(&t);
    cout << put_time(&tm, "%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S") << endl;
    for( ; it != myMap.end(); ++it){
        cout << it->first << ":" << it->second->counter);
    }
    arrayLock--;
    mu1.unlock();
}

void updateObject(MyObj* myObj){
    while (arrayLock > 0)
        Sleep(0);
    inThreadCount++;
    async(std::launch::async, myObj->update(true));
}
```

PS, I realize that there is a tiny window of opportunity for error between Sleep() and arrayLock/inThreadCount++. That's part of the problem I want to solve!

Comment: there are multiple compilation errors. like your line with async i wrong, myObj.update returns void and there is no myObj declared, myObj::update is private ...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimum Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Explain your goal more clearly if you can. 
Also there are no threads in your code as std::async does not necessarily create a new thread.

Comment: Sorry, was mostly pseudocode.. I'll fix it up. I'll rephrase the goal too

Comment: How about a more descriptive title as well...

Comment: Why not just have 1 lock for the array and be done with it? You lock it, access the array, then unlock it.

Comment: @rustyx The same item shouldn't be accessed twice at once. Mostly trying to work with an existing, inadequate system without changing it too much here. But looking at the example again, i realize that there's really no point in locking the array here... I'll have to find a better generic example!

Comment: "*The same item shouldn't be accessed twice at once*" == you need a mutex, a.k.a. a lock. Have a look at std::mutex and lock_guard.

Comment: There is a mutex there. Still trying to think of a showable example.. Was looking for something like if any X, block Y from acting but allow Z to act.

Comment: Got it! give me a min

Comment: @rustyx How about that? A more feasible example (Although probably not runnable code, I don't have access to an IDE right now)

Comment: @dandan78 I'm open to suggestions if you can sum up the question in less than a paragraph!

Comment: Is  GetSnapshot a member function of myObject class ? If not, how does it access the mutex ?  
Another problem : GetSnapshot wait until  `inThreadCount <= 0` after acquiring the mutex, but `inThreadCount` needs to acquire the mutex to be decremented : you have a possible deadlock. The map iterator in `GetSnapshot` and `myMap` does not have the same signature.

Comment: @Clonk it's accessing a different mutex. My bad for using the same name (fixed!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're asking for a shared mutex.
A shared mutex (or read-write mutex) allows many threads to lock an object in parallel while also allowing one thread at a time to lock it exclusively.

In simple terms, if a thread requests shared access it is granted unless a thread holds the object exclusively. A thread is granted exclusivity when the object isn't held (shared or exclusively) by any other thread.

It's common use is read-write exclusivity. See shared access to read and exclusive access to write. That's valid because a data race can only occur when two ore more threads access the same data and at least one of them is a write operation. Multiple readers is not a data race.

There are normally overheads in implementing a shared lock as opposed to an exclusive lock, and the model only normally helps where there are 'many' readers 
 that read 'frequently' and write operations are 'infrequent'. What 'many', 'frequent' and 'infrequent' mean depends on the platform and problem in hand.

That's exactly what a shared mutex is for.
C++17 supports that out of the box with `std::shared_mutex` but I noticed the question is tagged C++11.

Some implementations have offered that for some time (it's a classic locking strategy)
Or you can try `boost::shared_mutex<>`.

NB: One of the challenges in a shared-lock is to avoid live-lock on the writer.
If there are many readers that read frequently it can be easy the writer to get 'locked out' indefinitely and never progress (or progress very slowly).
A good shared lock will provide some guarantee of the writer eventually getting a turn. That may be absolute priority (no writers allowed to start after a thread starts waithing

Comment: Hmm... close to what I was looking for (and probably useful in the future!), but I'm for something a little different. The ability to cut access to multiple objects at once. Like a selective lock--not set by one object, but still blocked by it

Comment: While the classic use of a shared lock is for many reads and one write. It's not tied to that purpose. I think you're saying that threads may be accessing different elements in the collection, but sometimes a thread needs exclusive access to the whole collection.
The answer is still a shared mutex! Just interpret holding the shared lock as being in 'shared' mode and holding the exclusive lock as 'exclusive' mode! Make `mu1` a shared lock and leave `mu2` as a 'plain' mutex.

Comment: One (possible) issue though. What's the order of granting a lock? If I request the exclusive lock while it's shared lock, is there a possibility that the exclusive lock will be forever blocked? Or are lock attempts queued? Or prioritized? The details don't seem to be included in cppreference.com

Comment: Also not sure if that would be an implementation specific detail or part of a shared mutex design pattern

Comment: @Mars It's typically an implementation detail. Though if there are many shared lockers there's a clear risk of 'live lock' on a exclusive request. You could get to the point where there's always a shared lock. So typically implementations will do something to make sure the exclusive lock eventually wins. They may be as simple as block acquiring a shared lock when there are any pending exclusive locks. But that too can cause live lock on shared locks! That's why I didn't offer an implementation. A good general purpose shared mutex isn't trivial.